# How can I pass a JSON string as a prop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, shopify, liquid, vuejs3

I am using Vue.js with Shopify, and I'm hoping to pass objects from Liquid into a Vue component as a prop. For example, if I register the Vue component product-tile, and I want to use [Shopify's product object in Liquid](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/product) and convert it directly into an object in Vue, I would like to be able to do something like this:

`<product-tile product='{{ product | json }}'></product-tile>`

Note that the curly brackets here are Liquid and not Vue, I'm using [delimiters](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#delimiters). My current workaround is to put the data I need in hidden input fields that I then pull in from the DOM after the component is mounted, but being able to pass the Liquid directly into the Vue component would be a much cleaner solution.

I get errors with the above code because Vue doesn't seem to like a JSON string being passed in as a prop in this way. The specific error is:

> Template compilation error: Unquoted attribute value cannot contain U+0022 ("), U+0027 ('), U+003C (<), U+003D (=), and U+0060 (`).

Is there a other way to accomplish this without my current workaround?

Comment: That’s because you’re inserting a raw JSON into the prop, and the characters in it are reserved for HTML. This feels like an XY a problem: why can’t you fetch the product data using Ajax?

Comment: I could fetch using AJAX, however given how Shopify's AJAX API works and the fact that this component appears multiple times on a page I would have to make dozens of API calls for data that I already have available in the template on page load. It feels like it would be far more efficient if I could pass this data directly into the Vue component as a prop.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [uicrooks/shopify-foundation-theme](https://github.com/uicrooks/shopify-foundation-theme/blob/4ba52440a024c1ae9cd15240683007605e2beed3/shopify/sections/main-product.liquid#L122), they were able to make it work with an extra filter.

```
<product-tile :product="{{ product | json | replace: '"', "'" }}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<product-tile :product="product"></product-tile>

<product-tile :product="JSON.parse(product)"></product-tile>
```

and define prop as

```
props: {
  product: Object
}
```